# What's the difference between "to have been involved" and "to be involved"?

Tags: tense, difference

What's the differences between the following sentences:

> 1. I'm very proud to have been involved in this project.

> 2. I'm very proud to be involved in this project.

Are they all correct?

Comment: The first sentence is semantically equivalent to "I'm very proud that I *was* involved in the project". The perfect (HAVE+past participle) is used because *to* cannot be followed by a past-tense verb.

Comment: to involve (av)   - to be involved (pv);      to have involved (av)  -  to have been involved (pv);  Just notice the change while changing the voice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're both correct. In the first sentence, the project you're talking about is over. It's something that happened in the past—a year ago, a month ago, a week ago or maybe it has just ended. But the idea is that it's no longer being worked on or in development. It's a done deal, in other words. In the second sentence, on the other hand, the project is something that's still ongoing or something that's about to be launched. Put another way, as you speak about how proud you are to be involved in it, you and your coworkers are either already working on it or in the process of preparing to start working on it. Take a look at these examples and tell me if you can see the difference:

> — We spent millions of dollars and thousands of man-hours building this bridge. But we did it! So, what do you think?
>   — The only thing that I can say, sir, is that I'm very proud to have been involved in this project! It was such an honor to work with the best engineers in this field.
>
> — Soon, we're going to start working on the development of a new app for the iPhone and the board of directors decided that you're going to be part of the team. What do you say?
>   — All I can say is that I'm very proud to be involved in this project, sir! I'm going to get to work as soon as it starts.